# Pass React Ref from parent to child in order to get DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a parent and a child component. I need to access the parent's `HTMLelement` in the child component.

I have a working but unclean solution involving
`this.setState({ domNode: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this) });` in the parent's `componentDidMount` which is just wrong on many levels.

How can i do this using `createRef()` in the parent to pass its ref as a prop to the child and then how do i get the DOM node with type `HTMLElement` from the ref?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html ?

Comment: Can I know why you want to access the parent's HTML element in child component, I mean what are you trying to achieve? so that I can suggest a better solution.

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G of course. I am using a library called AntDesign. One of its components offers an API that lets me define a parent. Specifically the getPopupContainer() from https://ant.design/components/select/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best solution that doesn't involve any hack would be to pass a function from parent to child that return the ref of the element to be access

**Parent:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.domElem = React.createRef();
}

getElem = () => {
    return this.domElem;
}

render() {
    return (
       <div>
           <div id="elem" ref={this.domElem}>Test Elem</div>
           <Child getParentElem={this.getElem}/>
       </div>
    )
}
```

**Child:**

```
getParentRef = () => {
   const elem = this.props.getParentElem();
}
```

Comment: I agree with this, it looks clean.

Comment: So once i have a ref in my child component, i can access it via `myRef.current`. How do i get an `element` out of that similar to the `findDOMNode()` method?

Comment: If the ref is specified on the HTML element you would get the element directly and if it is specified on the Component you would need to use findDOMNOde

Comment: For some reason, when i do `this.props.getParentElem()` in the child component, i am getting `{current: null}`

Comment: @JamesPoulose Where did you run it? You should do it in `useEffect` or `componentdidmount` to ensure the ref has value

Comment: example code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pass-a-parents-ref-to-a-child-forked-khycf5

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Shubham Khatri is proper to be mentioned. The small correction I want to show, there is no need to invoke a callback function `getElem()` from child to parent to receive the parent's ref. It can be passed directly the ref to child `<Child getParentElem={this.domElem}/>`
I see few user complaining to receive `{current: null}` at child. Please check if the components UI is delivered by a framework, like e.g. Semantic-UI. Probably there could be other methods to hook a ref from a component. In Semantic-UI have to be wrapped the parent component in `<Ref innerRef={ ... }> ... </Ref>`