# how can put ref to props.children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, ref

I want wrapping module for multi use.

so, I make an ItemComponent

```
export const DragItem = (props: DragProps) => {
  const [{... }, fooRef] = useFoo({

  })

  return (
    props.children // how can i send fooRef to here??
  )
}
```

I should send ref to props.children
Is it possible?

Comment: explain in details your problem ans if possible provide fiddle or stackblitz

Comment: I just want to send ref for any component from props

Comment: see if this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940884/pass-react-ref-from-parent-to-child-in-order-to-get-dom-element

Comment: may be this can help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this : https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-williams-ywv9m
You need to use  `React.cloneElement` to attach/pass extra data to children

```
export const DragItem = (props: DragProps) => {
  const [foo, fooRef] = React.useState({});
  var childrenWithRef = React.Children.map(props.children, function(child) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, { fooRef: fooRef });
  });
  return childrenWithRef;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
export const DragItem = (props: DragProps) => {
  const [{... }, fooRef] = useFoo({

  })

  return (
    React.cloneElement(props.children, { ref: fooRef })
  )
}
```